# Cookie operations don't work in Opera or Chrome

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to write a code which will ask a visitor of the website to enter his name, then i will store that name in a variable, next time he enter the page there will be a message saying "hello ..." 
... = whatever name he put.

the code works in safari/IE/firefox but not in opera/chrome, i don't know why!! 
The prompt message appear but the value is never stored. Each time it ask me again to enter the name
here is the code

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function checkCookie() {
    var name = getCookie("username");
    if (name != "") {
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "Welcome again " + name;
    } 
    else {
        name = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (name != "" && name != null) {
            setCookie("username", name, 365);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Which part doesn't work?

Comment: The `while` loop in `getCookie` can be replaced with `c = c.trim();`

Comment: The prompt message appear but the value is never stored. Each time it ask me again to enter the name